# IP masquerading and NAT

Tags: router, ip, nat

What is the difference between IP masquerading and NAT?

Do both of them have the same limitation?

Does the statement "IP masquerading cannot provide full internet connections to the hosts which hide behind it" apply to NAT, too?

Can I use IP masquerading in the router instead of NAT?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

IP masquerading is just another name for NAT/NAPT, commonly used on Linux systems. Both mean the same thing.